# Consume ProjectData from Project Server 2013 Workflow - Forbidden

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, project-server, ms-project-server-2013

I need to consume data from `http://project/pwa/_api/ProjectData` Project OData service from Project Server 2013 Workflow.
But I got "Forbidden" Response Code.
User have all rights (Administrator, Site Collection Administrator).
Consuming other endpoints (ProjectServer, Web, Lists) successfull, even from other site collections and farms.
When I need configure a security to successfully consume ProjectData?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to provide credentials

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.ProjectServer.Client;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string pwaPath = "http://ServerName/pwa/";
    const string password = "pwa_password";
    const string userName = "user_name@your_company.onmicrosoft.com";

    var projContext = new ProjectContext(pwaPath); 
    var secureString = new SecureString();

    password.ToCharArray().ToList().ForEach(x => secureString.AppendChar(x));

    projContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, secureString);

    // Get the list of published projects in Project Web App.
    projContext.Load(projContext.Projects);
    projContext.ExecuteQuery();

    Console.WriteLine("\nThere are {0} projects", projContext.Projects);
}
```